# How to search filter/domain restricted records in Odoo tree view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-view

I have a tree view inside an odoo-10 with 15,000 records. On the tree view action I have applied a domain that filters out records from the original count and shows some 100 records on the screen.

My problem starts here, Now when I search for some record inside filter box, Odoo shows/calculates result from only those 100 records Whereas, I want filtered result from all of my 15,000 records. Could it be possible? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: can you show your domain?

Comment: <field name="domain">[('is_valid', '=', False), ('is_approved', '=', False),('stock_picking_ids', '!=', False)]</field>

 With this filter I am able to get limited data as per the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify function search to achieve what you want.

In your model, overwrite function search

`def search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False):`

to modify `args`. In your case, you have to remove original domains from args and set args contain only the latest domain